# Uncompilable source code

Tags: java, netbeans, payara

When I deploy my application in payara it gives me this error could help me attach the code to give me some idea how to solve it

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - Erroneous tree type: <any>
at gt.gob.mp.siamp.rrhh.business.ejb.ws.config.RestWsConfig.addRestResourceClasses(RestWsConfig.java:30)
at gt.gob.mp.siamp.rrhh.business.ejb.ws.config.RestWsConfig.getClasses(RestWsConfig.java:23)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig$RuntimeConfig$3.run(ResourceConfig.java:1234)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$2.call(Errors.java:289)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$2.call(Errors.java:286)
```

```
@ApplicationPath("/rest")
public class RestWsConfig extends Application {

    private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(RestWsConfig.class);

    @Override
    public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {

        try {
            log.debug("Loading rest config");
            Set<Class<?>> resources = new java.util.HashSet<>();
            addJsonProvider(resources);
            addRestResourceClasses(resources);
            return resources;
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            return null;
        }
    }

    private void addRestResourceClasses(Set<Class<?>> resources) {
        //resources.add(gt.gob.mp.siamp.mailer.business.ejb.ws.MailerWs.class);
        resources.add(gt.gob.mp.siamp.rrhh.ejb.cto.IContratosService.class);
        log.debug("rest resources added");
    }

    private void addJsonProvider(Set<Class<?>> resources) {
        try {
            //Class jsonProvider = Class.forName("org.glassfish.jersey.jackson.JacksonFeature");
            Class jsonProvider = Class.forName("org.glassfish.jersey.moxy.json.MoxyJsonFeature");
            // Class jsonProvider = Class.forName("org.glassfish.jersey.jettison.JettisonFeature");
            resources.add(jsonProvider);
            log.debug("JSon provider added");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            log.error(ex);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks like a Netbeans specific issue. Deselect "Compile on save":
http://stackoverflow.com/a/22927691/212224

Comment: I tried to do that but I did not work

Comment: What didn't work? Turning it off didn't work? It didn't change anything? Did the error change at all?

Comment: Are you using maven to build the application? Try clean&build of the project and check if there are any errors. Your code seems to be compilable, but sometimes weird things happen during repetitive builds until all is cleaned and rebuilt.